# Use of enum and dictionary when search by value and search by key in equal proportions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to have a map where i sometimes need to access key by value.
But if i use dictionary, i have to iterate through the dictionary to get key using value

```
Color = {"RED" : 3,"BLACK" : 5, "GREEN" : 10}

for color in Color:
    if(Color[color] = 5):
        return color
```

But with enum i can easily find the key by value(aliasing)

```
class colors(Enum):
    RED = 3
    BLACK = 5
    GREEN = 10

colors(5).name
```

How is enum implemented as data structure that facilitates this? is it different from dict? and which method should i prefer for my problem?

What is best of both approaches in terms of space and time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary uses keys and values, while an enum uses attributes of an object to store/access values. you can call the items from the dictionary like so:

```
color["BLACK"]
```

using dict:

```
colors = {"RED" : 3,"BLACK" : 5, "GREEN" : 10}
def getKey(dct,value):
     return [key for key in dct if (dct[key] == value)]

print(getKey(colors,5)[0])
```

in comparison to using an enum (as you already specified):

```
from enum import Enum
class colors(Enum):
    RED = 3
    BLACK = 5
    GREEN = 10

print(colors(5).name)
```

Comment: reversing values and keys is not an option. so in this case should i use enum?

Comment: how wouldn't it be an option?

Comment: Because search by key and value happens almost equal number of times in my problem

Comment: I guess in that case, then using an enum could be somewhat preferable, ill edit my answer to show you a comparison.